# Хочу чтобы бот ответил на сообщение

Tags: python, telebot

я только учусь и я думаю что вопрос максимально простой,но я залез на кучу сайтов и если просто говоря не могу найти решение

использую telebot

кароч команда /truefalse

далее бот реагирует на команду,отправляет сообщение "введите вопрос"

тут я хочу чтобы пользователь мог вписать что угодно(мне не обязателен определенный вопрос)

после бот отправляет из списка рандомный ответ

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['truefalse'])
def truefalse(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Ваш вопрос?')
# вот тут как я понимаю бот должен принимать сообщение
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, random.choice(bingo))

bingo = ['Правда','ПиздGGGж','Отвечаю','Владосу осталось три дня']
```

не знаю как я искал но у меня либо бот ломался либо сразу отправлял и "введите вопрос" и ответ рандом

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте:

```
import random
bingo = ['Правда','ПиздGGGж','Отвечаю','Владосу осталось три дня']

@bot.message_handler(commands=['truefalse'])
def truefalse(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Введите свой вопрос')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,test)


def test(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,f'{random.choice(bingo)}')
```

bot.register_next_step_handler() для ожидания ответа от пользователя и перехода к хенделеру test после ответ
Библиотека random для случайного выбора из списка методом choice()